# How to find the farthest point on a known graph from a known line?

Tags: calculus, geometry

How to find the farthest point on a known graph from a known line?
For example, farthest point on the graph of $f(x)=x^3$, and the line segment that passes between $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$

Comment: This problem seems ill-posed...

Answer (score 1):

There are two farthest points $(\infty, \infty)$ and $(-\infty, -\infty)$, both have equal $\perp$ distance from the curve and both are on the line $x=y$, which is formed by joining $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$.